# Python plotnine - adding a rectangular area

Tags: python, plotnine

I have started using plotnine and would like to create a chart with a red area above 40 and a blue area below -40.

[chart with red and blue rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEsCv.png)

I was able to approximate it with the following code, but it seems hacky.  What is the "correct" way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

vals = np.random.randint(-50, 50, size=20)
df = pd.DataFrame({"val":vals})
ggplot(df, aes(x=df.index, y = 'val')) \
   + geom_line() \
   + geom_hline(yintercept=40, size=20, colour='red', alpha=0.5) \
   + geom_hline(yintercept=-40, size=20, colour='blue', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: perhaps geom_rect()?

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked.  I am not sure why it did not work before.

Comment: I will type it below as an answer to complete this post

Answer (score 1):

You can add a rectangular area with plotnine using the geom `geom_rect()`.

```
+geom_rect(data = dfwithnumbersyoulike, aes(xmin = yourxmin, xmax = yourxmax, ymin = yourymin, ymax = yourymax, fill = #ff0000, alpha = 0.7)) #red
+geom_rect(data = dfwithnumbersyoulike2, aes(xmin = yourxmin2, xmax = yourxmax2, ymin = yourymin2, ymax = yourymax2, fill = #0000ff, alpha = 0.7)) #blue
```

(Or just transform the`geom_hline`s to be above `40` and below `-40`)